# JUnit testing custom exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, junit4

I'm using JUnit and not quite sure how to test custom exception class. I have created,

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    //@param message is the exception message

    public CustomException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    //@param message is the exception message
    //@param cause is the cause of the original exception

    public CustomException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

main class would have many try catch such as:

```
catch (ParseException e) {

    throw new CustomException("Date format incorerect", e);
```

and I'm not sure how to write the test class for it.

Comment: To know how to test something you need a specification of what that thing *ought* to do. You have not provided such a specification,  so this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [page](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing) should tell you everything you need to know. For the simplest case, which seems to be your case, just do this:

```
@Test(expected= CustomException.class) 
public void myTest() { 
  MyObject obj = new MyObject();
  obj.doSomethingThatMightThrowCustomException(); 
}
```

Comment: I try your suggestion but Intellij says that CustomException must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```
public class YourTestClass
{
    @Test
    public void yourTestMethodName() throws CustomeException {
        //your logic goes here.
        if (condition) {
           throw new CustomeException(<Message to display while throwing an error>);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can try the following site http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html